# How to retrieve json sub array value by key name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I've been trying  and trying to reach the right code for my json array which comes from a mysql database.
so to be clear let me post the code first.

**json Array(from the php code below)**

```
{"query":"han","user_info":[{"username":"HannaShissler"},{"avatar":"\/\/en.wetube.org\/tubes\/uploads\/avatar\/no_avatar.png-50"},{"username":"Athanh"},{"avatar":"\/\/en.wetube.org\/tubes\/uploads\/avatar\/no_avatar.png-50"},{"username":"sabhan"},{"avatar":"\/\/en.wetube.org\/tubes\/uploads\/avatar\/no_avatar.png-50"}]}
```

**PHP**

```
$search_sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like '%$query%' order by id DESC LIMIT 5");        
$data = array();
while($array = $db->fetch_assoc($search_sql)){
    $data[]['username'] = $array['username'];
    $data[]['avatar'] = DOMAIN.TUBES.UPLOADS.AVATAR.resizer($array['avatar'],'50','');
}
$data = array(
'query'=>$query,
'user_info'=>$data
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Js/ajax/json**

```
success: function(data){

$.each(data.user_info, function(index,value) {
    alert(value.username);
  }); 

}
```

now what I'm trying to get is the username of the sub array of user_info individually.
also if there's another way to rewrite the php code because I feel I'm doing something wrong. 
please help on this guys, I'm depending on you. or I will have to go back to html instead of json data :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would change

```
{"username":"HannaShissler"},{"avatar":"\/\/en.wetube.org\/tubes\/uploads\/avatar\/no_avatar.png-50"}
```

to

```
{"username":"HannaShissler","avatar":"\/\/en.wetube.org\/tubes\/uploads\/avatar\/no_avatar.png-50"}
```

(one object per user rather putting avatar and username in different objects)

the code to do that would be

```
$search_sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like '%$query%' order by id DESC LIMIT 5");        
$data = array();
while($array = $db->fetch_assoc($search_sql)){
    $data[]=array(
        'username' => $array['username'];
        'avatar' => DOMAIN.TUBES.UPLOADS.AVATAR.resizer($array['avatar'],'50','')
    );
}
$data = array(
'query'=>$query,
'user_info'=>$data
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: will that fix the json as well?

Comment: if you change how you populate $data to my code json will have one object per user which should also make your JS working and show usernames on each alert.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was the php that was wrong, because when I was fetching all data from the mysql table and send them to json, it was working fine, but after i was getting specific columns that what made it fail doing the job.